# ASP.Net MySqlDatabase Null Value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

I have below code in my ASP.Net Web Forms Page C#,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string selectTruckQuery = "SELECT * from truck where truck_id='" + truckID + "'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectTruckQuery, conn);
            foreach (DbDataRecord rowData in cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("truck_id")))
                    IdNo.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("truck_id"));

                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("registration_no")))
                    RegistrationNo.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("registration_no"));

                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("make")))
                    TMake.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("make"));

                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("model")))
                    TMod.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("model"));

                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("engine_no")))
                    TEng.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("engine_no"));


                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("chassis_no")))
                    TChass.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("chassis_no"));


                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_name")))
                    TDriver.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_name"));

                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_contact_no")))
                    TNo.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_contact_no"));

                if (!rowData.IsDBNull(rowData.GetOrdinal("status")))
                    TStat.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("status"));

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I want to get the values from MySqlDatabase, I am getting the values `null` from MySqlDatabase, I'm quite sure that the code is correct.

All output is Null, what supposed to be the problem of this?

Please help me!

Comment: using debugger see what does `selectTruckQuery ` contains and use the same query in MySql then you can find the error.

Comment: You are on page load event, make sure that `truckID` has a value assigned to it before passing it on to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterised query.

Please try below.

```
conn.Open();
string selectTruckQuery = "SELECT * from truck where truck_id=@truckId";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectTruckQuery, conn);
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@truckId", truckId);
```

Convert truckId depending on the datatype of your field.